# Como sinalizar uma duplicada para mais de uma pergunta?

Tags: suporte

Pode ser uma dúvida até trival, mas sinceramente não sei como fazer :)

Vejo perguntas marcadas como duplicas de mais de um outra pergunta existente, como essa por exemplo: [How is that possible? (Java)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/514668/how-is-that-possible-java)

[image: imagem]

Quando eu sinalizo uma pergunta como duplicada, só consigo marcar uma resposta, como se faz para marcar outras respostas?